# google maps v3 JS gradient / multiple paths on directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, path

is there any way to set the `polylineOptions` on `DirectionsRenderer` to be a gradient ( to create a fade out effect)?

I've searched for a gradient options, with no luck.

other possibility it may be by getting the direction result by parts (percentage or something) and then redraw multiple lines with different opacity

what i need is something like this:

```
                       |     Opacity   |
                       |100% 50%  10% 0|
Start-------\/                   -------End
             -------\/          /\
                     ------------
```

the reason for this it's because my application has some non-exact location marker, so a circle and faded path would help on this

Answer (score 0):

DirectionsRenderer can't accept opacities.
But google.maps.polyline primitive accepts,"strokeColor","strokeOpacity","strokeWeight",etc.
So,You should "render" the path line yourself(with reading DirectionService response)